# Unable to create new simple volume. C:\Windows\inf - Not default?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drivers, disk-volume

Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I attempt to create a new "simple volume" in *Disk Management* (or even *Diskpart*), the operations hangs and eventually end up with this error:
 [image]

However, before the error above appears, I noticed that in *Device Manager* appears an **Unknown device** (under *Other Devices*), if I right-click on **Unknown device** and select *Update Driver Software*, and I browse to **C:\Windows\inf**, it actually finds and detects a **Generic volume** and the new "simple volume" ends up being created just fine.

It's as if Windows has lost the ability to look for drivers in C:\Windows\inf by default.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/where-setup-searches-for-drivers
Somehow **C:\Windows\inf** was missing from the **DevicePath** key.